# How can I add a treenode to treeview using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to manipulate the treeview nodes(add node, add child node, delete node,and move up,down) from client side only and then do postback to compare changes and save to database. 
When I add the nodes to the tree I set the nodes.selectedacction=none

Anybody knows how I can achive this using jquery or any for free control

Comment: every time I use a `treeview` I tend to use a plugin to make things easier, like http://www.jstree.com, and then use their events to update my persistence object/ db

Comment: Thanks dude I'll watch this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding, deleting  items to the treeview using javascript is not a big deal. But since you want to access the values in the backend, it is not a simple task. My best suggestion is you can have a JSON object for the treeview and access it using JavaScript and then generate the tree. then instead of bostback, you can pass the generated JSON to backend using ajax request. then you can compare two objects.

Comment: Oh men It sounds very hard. First I'll need improve my javasript and ajax to do that... I still do postbacks and all happy thanks for the answer

Comment: Ok then wrap it using UpdatePanel